# How to know any UI rendering is completed in automation code

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, ui-automation

I am wanting to know a button is rendered on main window UI or not. This button rendering is depending on server response result (written in Objective C). If server response comes perfectly it becomes render perfectly (VISIBLE) otherwise it is not present there (INVISIBLE). And whenever it becomes visible I always tap on it for further next process.

I wrote code

```
UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(200);
   //My code
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();
```

By the above code I have to wait till 200 sec but my concern is I want to wait but whenever object is on screen I don't want keep me busy in WAITING MODE.

How will I write code in automation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this might give you idea how to follow-up:

For your view implement an *accessibilityValue* method which returns a *JSON* formatted value:

```
- (NSString *)accessibilityValue
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"{'MyButtonisVisible':%@}", 
            self.MyButton.isHidden ? @"false" : @"true"];
}
```

Then somehow you can access it from your test javascript:

```
var thisproperty = eval("(" + element.value() + ")");

if (thisproperty.MyButtonisVisible) {
    UIATarget.localTarget().tap({"x":100, "y":100});
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the name different when you enable the button you can do this:

```
var awesomeButton = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0];
UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(200);
awesomeButton.withName("My Awesome Button");
if (awesomeButton.isVisible()) {
    UIALogger.logError("Error no awesome button!");
}
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();
```

withName will repeatedly test the name and control will return to your script once the name matches or when the time out is reached.

**Per Apple's Doc**

**withName**: 
Tests if the name attribute of the element has the given string value. If the match fails, the test is retried until the current timeout expires.

**Timeout Periods**:
If the action completes during the timeout period, that line of code returns, and your script can proceed. If the action doesn’t complete during the timeout period, an exception is thrown.

https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/e808aa/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20